# Change 1 data-value without changing all the three

Tags: jquery

My goal with the code is to when `data-isChar` is true the `locationsSelect` is going to show only when the button on the box where it is set to true

Right now I only get that when i click `SPELA` and the `data-isChar="true"` it appears on all the boxes

I'm really new to coding and searched on the internet and not found anything of the things i noted above so this is my only try to this project

(BOOTSTRAP 4, JQUERY)

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div class="characters">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col box-1" data-isChar="false" data-char="1">
                    <h4 class="character-name">Tom karaktär</h4>
                    <footer class="character-info">
                        <p>Skapa en ny karaktär</p>
                    </footer>
                        <div class="buttons">
                            <button id="play-char" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#locationSelect">SPELA</button>
                            <button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">RADERA</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <div class="col box-2" data-isChar="false" data-char="2">
                    <h4 class="character-name">Tom karaktär</h4>
                    <footer class="character-buttons">
                        <p class="character-info">Skapa en ny karaktär</p>
                    </footer>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button id="play-char" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#locationSelect">SPELA</button>
                        <button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">RADERA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col box-3" data-isChar="false" data-char="3">
                    <h4 class="character-name">Tom karaktär</h4>
                    <footer class="character-info">
                        <p>Skapa en ny karaktär</p>
                    </footer>
                    <div class="buttons">
                        <button id="play-char" class="btn btn-success" data-target="#locationSelect">SPELA</button>
                        <button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger">RADERA</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
    $(".buttons #play-char").click(function() {
        if ($(".col").attr("data-isChar") === "false") {
            $(this).attr("data-target", "#createModal")
            $("#createModal").modal("show")
        } else {
            $("#locationSelect").modal("show")
        }
    })
```

Comment: Your're using the ids play-char and delete multiple times, but ids have to be unique.

Comment: i don't think that's the problem. it's the meaning to use them multiple times. They have the same function

Comment: Why do you have multiple id's with the same value? If you want to give multiple elements the same selector use the class method.

Comment: not the problem still..

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the logic you're explaining. Is the button bound to each element? How are you trying to 'target' the elements that are selected by the click?